# Changing the generators of an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $p,q \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ have the same $y$-degree and denote the ideal they generate by $I=\langle p,q \rangle$.

Obviously, the ideal $J$ generated by $P=p+(p-q)^n$ and $Q=q+(p-q)^n$,
$n \geq 1$, equals $I$.
Indeed, $J \ni P-Q=p-q$ and then $J \ni P-(P-Q)^n=p$ and $J \ni Q-(P-Q)^n=q$ etc.

Assume that $y \in I$ and write $y=Hp+Kq$, for some $H,K \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
(Necessary $H,K$ have the same $y$-degree, since $p,q$ have the same $y$-degree).

> **Question:** Could one find $\tilde{H},\tilde{K} \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$
> such that $y=\tilde{H}P+\tilde{K}Q$?

**Remark, a simpler question:** Instead of $P,Q$ above, consider $P=ap+bq$ and $Q=cp+dq$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfy $ad-bc \neq 0$;
in that case we can take $\tilde{H}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}(dH-cK)$ and $\tilde{K}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}(-bH+aK)$.
(Just played with the adjoint matrix to obtain this result).
Indeed,
$$
\tilde{H}P+\tilde{K}Q=\frac{1}{ad-bc}(dH-cK)(ap+bq)+
\frac{1}{ad-bc}(-bH+aK)(cp+dq)=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}[(dH-cK)(ap+bq)+(-bH+aK)(cp+dq)]=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}[adHp+bdHq-acKp-bcKq-bcHp-bdHq+acKp+adKq]=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}[adHp-bcKq-bcHp+adKq]=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}[adHp-bcHp+adKq-bcKq]=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}[(ad-bc)Hp+(ad-bc)Kq]=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}[(ad-bc)(Hp+Kq)]=Hp+Kq=y.
$$

Any comments are welcome; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example, we have $y=Hp+Kq=H(P-(P-Q)^n)+K(Q-(P-Q)^n)=H(P-(P-Q)(P-Q)^{n-1})+K(Q-(P-Q)(P-Q)^{n-1})=P(H-H(P-Q)^{n-1}-K(P-Q)^{n-1})+Q(H(P-Q)^{n-1}+K+K(P-Q)^{n-1}).$

Comment: Thank you very much!